# Bluebird Javascript Promise: stop execution after dealing with specified error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've got a somewhat complicated flow that receives an `entryUrl` from a database, checks where it redirects to, and then updates it with an `exitUrl`.

Basically the flow should be like so:

- retrieve an `Url` without an exit url

  - get the `Url.entryUrl`'s headers using `request`

    - if there's an unexpected response or connection was reset, flag this `Url` and continue with the next one
  - parse the `exitUrl` resulting from the `request` performed

    - store the `exitUrl`
    - continue with the next `Url`
- if no `Url` available, try again after 5 seconds
- if any unexpected error in the above chain or subchains, try again after 60 seconds

My current implementation is like so, using the Bluebird javascript promise style:

```
function processNext() {
    return api.getUrlWithoutExitUrl()
    .then(function followEntryUrl(url)
    {
        if (!url || !url.entryUrl)
        {
            throw new NoUrlAvailableError();
        }

        log.info('getting exit url for ' + url.entryUrl);
        return [
            request({
                method              : 'HEAD',
                url                 : url.entryUrl,
                followAllRedirects  : true,
                maxRedirects        : 20
            })
            .catch(ResponseError, function()
            {
                log.error('got strange response');
            })
            .catch(ConnResetError, function()
            {
                log.error('connection was reset');
            })
            .then(function removeInvalidUrl()
            {
                log.info('remove invalid url'); //FIXME: after doing this, we should not continue with the other `then` calls
            }),
            url
        ];
    })
    .spread(function parseExitUrl(res, url)
    {
        if (!res[0] || !res[0].request || !res[0].request.uri || !res[0].request.uri.href)
        {
            throw new InvalidUrlError();
        }
        return [res[0].request.uri, url];
    })
    .spread(function storeExitUrl(parsedExitUrl, url)
    {
        return api.setUrlExitUrl(url, parsedExitUrl);
    })
    .then(processNext)
    .catch(InvalidUrlError, function()
    {
        log.info('an attempted url is invalid, should set as processed and continue with next immediately');
    })
    .then(processNext)
    .catch(NoUrlAvailableError, function()
    {
        log.info('no url available, try again after a while');
    })
    .delay(5000)
    .then(processNext)
    .catch(function(err)
    {
        log.error('unexpected error, try again after a long while');
        log.error(err);
        log.error(err.constructor);
    })
    .delay(60000)
    .then(processNext);
}
processNext();

function ResponseError(e)
{
    return e && e.code === 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT';
}

function ConnResetError(e)
{
    return e && e.errno === 'ECONNRESET';
}
```

Now, the problem is that if there's a `ConnResetError` or a `ResponseError`, the catch blocks are executed as they should be, but the `then` blocks following the `spread` call are also executed -- yet I want execution to stop after having done something after catching these 2 specific error types.

How would I achieve such flow of execution?

Comment: use global boolean variable stopExecution and set them once you get certain type of errors and check the same before executing inside spread function call

Answer (score 0):

Just like in synchronous code - if you have a `catch` in which you want to perform some processing and then propagate the error - you can rethrow it:

Synchronous code:

```
try {
    a = makeRequest();
} catch(e) { 
    // handle
    throw e;
}
```

With promises:

```
makeRequest().catch(e => {
    // handle
    throw e; // also a good idea to add data to the error here
});
```

Comment: isn't the idea that I don't want to propagate the error? I want to stop execution of the flow.

Comment: @Tom how would you do this in synchronous code? You can use cancellation (3.0 has pretty similar semantics, not running the rest of the chain but running `.finally` blocks) but it's pretty ugly here IMO - nesting one level also works - what would you like to ideally happen here if the code failed and threw an exception at some point - still signal normal completion to the outside?

Comment: if there is any error except those 2 I defined above, it should go to the last `catch` block -- if there is a `ConnResetError` or a `ResponseError` then it should only execute the single `then` statement right under the respective catches and then stop execution

Comment: You can use a predicate catch block (instead of a typed catch block) and implement the logic there - it's not pretty but that's how it works.

Comment: I thought I'm already using a predicate catch block, at `.catch(ResponseError, function()`

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Missed that. Then no - there is no trivial way to "escape" a chain - there is `return` semantics with generators (and cancellation) where only finally blocks are run - check out cancellation in 3.0 or alternatively nest one level - I can't see a way around this without restructuring your code at least a little.

Comment: Could you show me the nesting / restructuring example? I'm not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

From your inner promise, when you first `catch` the ResponseError or ConnResetError, you return normally (i.e. not throwing), so the subsequent promise chain succeeds, executing its `then()` and `spread()` branches, rather than failing and going to the `catch()` branches.

You probably want to rewrite your inner promise `catch` blocks like so:

```
...
.catch(ResponseError, function(err) {
     log.error('got strange response');
     throw err;
})
...
```

Basically, re-throw the `Error` you have caught if you want to continue treating it as an error.

Comment: But then I get `unhandled exception` error in the console